# Protect linux partition from windows

Tags: partition, windows, dual-boot, gparted

I want to duel boot windows and Ubuntu, however i don't want anything on windows to be able to access my Linux partition. Is there anyway to do this without encryption? As i don't want to slowdown read/write times on my Linux system.

Comment: What's your threat model? The last time I checked, Windows didn't have pre-installed support for any of the file systems your Linux is likely to use. On the other hand, with sufficient rights on the windows side, you can read (and write!) the hard drive byte by byte.

Comment: remove windows partition from /etc/fstab file to stop auto mounting windows partition @Da google

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 options, to stop deletion.

- Separate hard-disks, and hardware switches.
- If you want to do it with the same hard-disk, then you will need some virtualisation software to run under MS-Windows.

There is no other way, as MS-Windows is an operating system, it can do what ever it wants with the hardware.

To stop read, then you can use encryption (your solution).